# lessphp load error with file LESS

Tags: php, css, joomla, less, lessphp

I'm new with the lessphp library, I'm using Joomla and I'm working with a template, I'd like to compile a less file with a php file, this is way I'm using phpless, to compile my LESS file I'm using this code:

```
require "lessc.inc.php";
$less = new lessc;
echo $less->compileFile($this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template.'/config/config.less');
```

but also if the url is correct I'm constantly having this error:

> load error: failed to find
>   /mywebsite/templates/mytemplate/config/config.less

What I'm missing?

Comment: Is the file there at `/mywebsite/templates/mytemplate/config/config.less` dare I ask?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, yes the file is in that directory and I could reach it if I copy the path in the browser url field, I don't know if could depends that I'm working on Mamp.

Comment: Just making sure: it really is at the top of your system, `/`, not at the top of your project directory, `./`?

Comment: Hello, ok, I checked the code of my Joomla and I substitute with this code:
echo $less->compileFile(JURI::base().'templates/'.$this->template.'/config/vikcomponent_owr.less');

With this modification I saw that the url printed on the website error has been changed with:
load error: failed to find http://localhost:8888/mywebsite/templates/mytemplate/config/config.less
however if I copy this exactly url in my browser url field I can see the file, I can't understand why this is happening, I think this problem depends on Joomla

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the problem, I wrong the joomla string, I changed in this way and now it's working:

```
echo $less->compileFile(JPATH_SITE.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'templates'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->template.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.less');
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue but working with WordPress, since this is the better-ranked answer about the issue by Google, I'll share here the way to do it in WP:

```
$less->compileFile(dirname(__FILE__).'/wp-content/themes/your-theme/config.less');
```